# Register form fill up using bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet for facebook register form fill up, but code not working now.
Some months ago its working very good but now its not loading and not fill up register form.

Code:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var f = ["masud","Rahim"],
        l = ["rana","Miah"],
        d = document;
    switch (location.pathname) {
        case "/reg/":
            d.getElementsByName("firstname")[0].value = f[Math.floor(Math.random() * f.length)],
            d.getElementsByName("lastname")[0].value = l[Math.floor(Math.random() * l.length)],
            d.getElementsByName("reg_email__")[0].value = "+84973" + Math.floor(888888 * Math.random() + 111111),
            d.getElementsByName("sex")[0].value = "1", d.getElementsByName("birthday_day")[0].value = "18",
            d.getElementsByName("birthday_month")[0].value = "08",
            d.getElementsByName("birthday_year")[0].value = "1997",
            d.getElementsByName("reg_passwd__")[0].value = "112266";
            break;
        case "/changeemail":
            d.getElementsByName("new")[0].value = "zz" + Math.floor(888888 * Math.random() + 111111) + "@youremaildomain.com"
    }
})();
```

Whats wrong with this code? Please help me to fix it. thanks

Comment: If it worked previously, you should inspect FB's source code

Comment: `getElementsByName` are all same to facebook